# Which rings containing the complex field are, as vector spaces over that field, isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Which rings $R$ containing (as a subring) the complex field $\mathbb{C}$ are, as a vector space over that field, isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$?

In other words: what are the two-dimensional unital associative algebras over $\mathbb{C}$?  Note that we do not a priori assume $R$ to be a commutative ring.

Comment: You mean, what are the $2$-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I didn't know what an algebra is , I searched the google , and it seems yes I am actually asking what are the two dimensional algebras over $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb C$

Comment: Can someone please tell me why is this "off-topic" ??

Comment: @SouvikDey Because they find it too simple. Don't worry the closers are the ones at fault. It is a nice question. Look [here for the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Classification_of_low-dimensional_algebras).

Comment: @user152732: thanks for the link

Comment: @user152732 "Don't worry the closers are the ones at fault." Uninformed propaganda.

Answer (score 2):

In general, let $k$ be any field. If $R$ is a $2$-dimensional $k$-algebra, it must have a basis $\{ 1, x \}$ where $x$ is not a scalar multiple of $1$; in particular, it must be commutative, since it is generated by $x$. Since it is $2$-dimensional, $x^2 = ax + b$ for some $a, b \in k$, and it follows that $R \cong k[x]/(x^2 - ax - b)$. The isomorphism type of $R$ is now controlled by the possible types of monic quadratic polynomials over $k$. There are three cases:

1. $x^2 - ax - b$ has two distinct roots in $k$. In this case $R \cong k \times k$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.
2. $x^2 - ax - b$ is irreducible over $k$. In this case $R$ is a quadratic field extension of $k$.
3. $x^2 - ax - b$ has two repeated roots in $k$. In this case $R \cong k[x]/x^2$.

If $k$ is algebraically closed then the second case never occurs and we conclude that there are exactly two isomorphism types of $2$-dimensional $k$-algebras.

Comment: Why should $R$ be commutative ? In particular , can we not have $1.x \ne x.1$ ? Since $R$ is a v.s. we should have $1.x=x$ , since $k$ is a field we should also have $1.y=y.1=y , \forall y \in k$ , but does this necessarily imply $R$ is commutative  ?

Comment: @Souvik: no, we cannot. By definition, $1$ satisfies $1 \cdot x = x \cdot 1$ for all $x$. If you want something noncommutative you need to either drop the unit or increase the dimension.

Comment: By what definition $1.x=x.1$ ; please tell

Comment: @Souvik: $1$ is the multiplicative unit; by definition, that means that it satisfies $1 \cdot x = x \cdot 1 = x$.

Comment: But can it not be that $1$ is the multiplicative unit of only the containing field $k$ but not of the ring $R$ ?

Comment: @Souvik: the convention I'm using here is that "$k$-algebra" means "unital associative $k$-algebra," and "unital" here means that $1$ is the unit of the entire ring. If you want to relax this hypothesis, then say so explicitly.